# Prove a congruent of polynomial

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$  be a prime divisor of $n$. Prove that
$$\prod_{\substack{1\le k\le n\\\gcd(k,n) = 1}}(x-k) \equiv \prod_{1 \le k \le p-1} (x-k)^{\tfrac{\varphi(n)}{p-1}} \pmod{p}$$

Comment: **Hint:** For a given $r<p$, how many $k<n$ are there with $\gcd(k,n)=1$ and $k\equiv r\pmod p$?

Comment: Hint : Use the fact that $\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)= 1 \text{ if n =1 and 0 otherwise}$ and play with the sum and the product

Comment: $\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)= 0$, I don't understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varrho:\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ denote the reduction modulo $p$.
Then we have a surjective group homomorphism
$$\varrho^\times:(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times\to(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$$
Consequently,
\begin{align}
|\ker\varrho^\times|&=\frac{|(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times|}{|(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times|}\\
&=\frac{\varphi(n)}{\varphi(p)}\\
&=\frac{\varphi(n)}{p-1}
\end{align}